# Match words beginning with an asterisk and the following word using regex look ahead function

Tags: regex, match, regexbuddy

I need a regex expression which will match words that begin with an asterisk and the word that follows them. It will match `eismoud tempor` and `dolore magna` in the example below:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do *eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et *dolore magna aliqua.`

I'm using RegexBuddy.

Comment: What should happen if we have a string ending with a last word starting with an asterisk, like this: `...sed do *eiusmod`?

Comment: Please don't forget to choose the right answer if your question was solved ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this expression, please:

```
(?<!\S)\*\w+(?:[^\w]+\w+)?\b
```

To catch all the lines matching the regex you might replace the expression with the a line-capturing one:

```
^.*(?<!\S)\*\w+(?:[^\w]+\w+)?\b.*$
```

and then setting in `Design mode` of `Espresso` the `Multiline` option (the one at the window bottom, not in `Options` tab). Et voilà! The search results now contain all the lines that include our matches.

Comment: Alexey it works perfectly, thank you a million! If the last word in the line begins with an asterisk it should match that word only.(though I'm not sure if there are such words in my text).

Comment: @TotoKalvera You're welcome. I've added a non-capturing group `(?:...)` to have this case covered too.

Comment: This will only work if there is an alphanumeric character right *before* the asterisk.

Comment: @TimPietzcker You're right. Thank you. I've fixed that too :)

Comment: And now...you don't need the `\b` any more because there will always (by definition) be a word boundary between `*` and the following `\w+`. You could do a `(?<!\S)` before the `\*` to make sure that there is either whitespace or the start of the string before the `*` if that is what you're trying to express.

Comment: I'll try that thank you a lot guys! As a newbie to this, I'd need you to point me to how to export only lines with matches in Regex Buddy or Expresso, I just can't figure out how to do that in either program. I know how to extract lines without results and also how to export only matching results, but I do not know how I can export the whole lines containing matches, and only them. I have all the expression I need and they work perfectly, yours from earlier today Tim and Aleksey's now, now I only need to put it to work.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thank you again. The new version has your fix included :)

Comment: @TotoKalvera In Expresso you may `Run Match`, then the result will appear in `Search Results`. It can be copied  by right-clicking on the `Search Results` area and choosing `Copy Matched Text to Clipboard`. The result would be separated by a newline.

Comment: Thank you Alexey! I know I can do that, but I need the complete lines with the matching expression in them to be copied, not only the search results. I have to separate lines that contain the match from those that do not. In Expresso, when I validate the results I get a tick beside the lines that contain the match and X beside those that don't, now all I need it is to export the matching lines to txt file, which I still can't figure out how to do.

Comment: @TotoKalvera I've supplemented my answer with an approach you may use to get the matching lines.

Comment: The expression doesn't return any matches. I've ticked the multiline box in Options in Design Mode and tried but no matching results with the latter expression :(

Comment: @TotoKalvera Not the one that's in `Options`, but the one that's among checkboxes at the windows bottom.